# Why did this fondue become grainy and lumpy?

Tags: cheese, fondue

We made some fondue the other night, and instead of being a nice smooth dippable fondue texture, it came out grainy and lumpy.  What went wrong?

Here's the recipe that we used:

- 1 clove garlic
- 3/4 cup Dark Ale or Other Beer
- 1 cup Emmenthal Cheese, Shredded
- 1 1/2 cups Gruyere Cheese, Shredded
- 1/2 cup Appenzeller Cheese, Shredded
- 1 tbsp Corn Starch

Slice garlic in half, rub in fondue pot.  Warm beer without boiling.  Mix cornstarch and cheeses.  Stir cheese into beer, one handful at a time, allowing to melt in-between additions.

Comment: Do you remember when you had lumps? Was it when you added the corn starch? Or after a type of cheese?

Comment: Its happened to me before. My problem was an improper ratio of cheeses.

Comment: Sorry - I can't identify when the lumps & graininess occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your cheese curdled.

This happens to me if I overheat the mixture- especially in the presence of acid. (I don't have any experience with using beer.) The cornstarch is there as a safety net to prevent this but obviously it is not infallible.

Turn down the heat and try adding a little more corn starch- it may not get back to perfect fondue but you may be able to pull it back to edible.

Answer (score 2):

Your family will notice if you try to "Pull it back to edible" (that sounds disgusting). Maybe use something a little more acidic next time, like a dry wine, or just a touch of lemon (not much!) if you insist on using beer. It does sound like the heat was a little too high though if you're getting the infamous ball-o-cheese fondue, so turn the fire down, keep stirring (I once heard that stirring in a figure 8 pattern helps immensely), and don't feed your family that nasty crap you  made while you were learning. Just kidding love!

Comment: Alcohol plays the same role as the acid. Perhaps instead of more acidic the beer should just have more alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

Swiss guy taught me that the best way to avoid this is to marinate the grated cheese in the wine a few hours before making the fondue. Never had a grainy fondue since I started doing this!